# php if inside foreach wrong

Tags: php, foreach

I have a problem with if inside foreach.
The answer for code must be “Equal” but is “EqualEqual”.

Here is my code

```
$list=array(
    "X"     => "X",
    "0"     => "0",
    "2"     => "2",
    "3"     => "3"
);

$var="X";

foreach ($list as $key =>  $val){

    if ($var==$key) {
        echo 'Equal';        
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Wants to know why the result comes out EqualEqual, there's only one array element with the key "X" so, it should be Equal.

Comment: why not in_array() same keys and values

Comment: It's printing out Equal for "X" == "0" as well as for "X" == "X" - FYI

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: t3chguy gave the answer below. If you just want to know, if a certain key exists, you can use isset().

Comment: @RakeshSharma: Because `isset($list[$var])` would be faster, and `array_key_exist($var, $list)` is more reliable. `in_array` suffers from the same problem: loose comparison (no type & value check by default)

Comment: `in_array()` does give you an option for strict comparison; default is loose

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
if ($var===$key) {
    echo 'Equal';        
}
```

You need `===` because `var_dump($var==0);` returns true, which is after type juggling.

Comment: Why downvote? My answer does as the OP wants and is functional.

Comment: it's the answer, but explain why it's the answer. ( I didn't downvote)

Comment: Sometimes type juggling is really counter-intuitive

Comment: For clarification the == is a loose comparison syntax, it it will cast the variable to multiple types "type juggling" so if your comparing (int) 1 to (string) 1 you will get a true return. Using the === operator will not type juggle but will return an exact match. Comparing (int) 1 to (string) 1 will return false

Comment: So using === when comparing strings is recommended. Highly

Comment: If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.--- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @sgt that explanation makes a hell of a lot of sense, thanks.,

Comment: its a very big problem so whenever work with this type of condition use "==="

Comment: Guys, guys, guys; why am I the only up-vote on @sgt Answer, his goes far in depth and definitely deserves some upvotes!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump('X' == 0);//true
```

reference - `http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php`

```
var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
var_dump("1" == "01"); // 1 == 1 -> true
var_dump("10" == "1e1"); // 10 == 10 -> true
var_dump(100 == "1e2"); // 100 == 100 -> true
```

If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

```
$a == $b    Equal   TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

so, try to use "===" instead of "==".

Comment: Yes, but "===" not working if $var come from a $_GET variable

Comment: if form get, the same is happening?